# Excel to create pivot table using variables

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with 10 sheets. I tried to automate the creation of pivot table on each sheets through a macro. I recorded the macro for the first sheet called Timetables

Below are part of the scripts:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:= _        
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("WorksheetConnection_Timetables!$A$1:$D$382"), _
Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
"Timetables!R1C5", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:= _
xlPivotTableVersion15
```

Since each range of data to be used is different on each sheet. I tried to create a variable for that range.

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Activesheet

Dim wr As Range
Set wr = Range("A1", Range("D1").End(xlDown))
```

The question is how can I replace the range Timetables!$A$1:$D$382 with the variable on the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a range, you need a text string as the argument for the pivot table source data parameter.

```
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim TheRange As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WorksheetConnection_Timetables")

lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
TheRange = "WorksheetConnection_Timetables!$A$1:$D$" & lastrow
```

Then you can use that as the data source parameter:

```
..._
ActiveWorkbook.Connections(TheRange), _
...
```

Comment: Thanks Teylyn. I created text string variables as you suggested. I tested and it work now. Excellence!